# Debugging is not supported for python 2.5 or earlier?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

[image]

I keep getting this error in visual studios. There are currently no documentation that I can find that solves this error. Im using Pythong 3.7. Also, I get this same error when I try to debug a Django web application as well as a just regular python web application. I have also tested with Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Firefox, all of which give me the same error. The configuration is set up for 3.7

Comment: Sounds like Virtual Studio doesn't support Python 3.7 yet. It's still in Beta, I wouldn't expect there to be wide support just yet. Why are you using a pre-release version of Python? Why not use Python 3.6 for now?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Im not sure. I am just getting into python web development. I have 3.7 working for other compilers, but with a background in C++ i am most comfortable with visual studios. Ill try 3.6 and see if that solves anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your version of Visual studio doesn't support your current version of Python. Try either to update your Visual Studio or change the python version in your environment configuration to a previous one (e.g 3.6).

Comment: A simpler  fix might be to create  a new project with the correct version of Python if you haven't done much work.

Answer (score 1):

you need this :

[image]

change environnement to 3.6 or 3.7 (3.8 doesn't work in VS community 2017)